# Error response from daemon: No such image: <imagename>:<branchname>-<Dateandtime>

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I am getting error while pushing my image to cloudsmith because the build time and the push time does not match.

```yaml
steps:
        -
          name: Checkout
          uses: actions/checkout@v4
          with:
            path: xyz
            token: ${{ secrets.abcdef }}
        
       
           
        -
          name: Build Doocker Image
          run: |
           CURRENT_DATETIME=$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
           GITHUB_REF_CLEAN="${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}"
           IMAGE_TAG="$GITHUB_REF_CLEAN-$CURRENT_DATETIME"
           LATEST_TAG="latest"
           echo "Using CURRENT_DATETIME: $CURRENT_DATETIME"
           docker build -t myimage:$IMAGE_TAG -f ./myimage/Dockerfile .
           docker build -t myimage:latest -f ./myimage/Dockerfile .

          env:
            CURRENT_DATETIME: $(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
         
        -
          name: 'login to Cloudsmith'
          uses: docker/login-action@v2
          with:
               registry: docker.cloudsmith.io
               username: nop-ss
               password: ${{ secrets.ZAR }}
      
        - 
          name: 'push image to Cloudsmith' 
          run: |
           CURRENT_DATETIME=$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
           GITHUB_REF_CLEAN="${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}"
           IMAGE_TAG="$GITHUB_REF_CLEAN-$CURRENT_DATETIME"
           LATEST_TAG="latest"
            docker tag myimage:$IMAGE_TAG docker.cloudsmith.io/org/repo/myimage:$IMAGE_TAG
            docker tag myimage:latest docker.cloudsmith.io/org/repo/myimage:latest
            docker push docker.cloudsmith.io/org/repo/myimage --all-tags
```

I tried assigning the build date and time in a variable assign it in push stage

Comment: You need to determine the image label _once_, and use it in both steps that reference it. Or just use e.g. `docker/build-push-action` to do it in one step. Right now you use `date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S'` in two different places, so it's more-or-less inevitable that they'll be different values.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I tried keeping the build and push step in same block, but still the same issue. Any example if you can share ?